# Python one-liner to make strings lowercase and leave numbers as is

Tags: python

Is there a way to write a one-liner which converts strings to lowercase and leaves numbers alone? So far I have this:

```
names = ["a","Abc","EFG",45,65]
newlist = [n.lower() for n in names if isinstance(n, basestring)]
print newlist 

>>>['a', 'abc', 'efg']
```

I would like this

```
>>>['a', 'abc', 'efg', 45 ,65]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a conditional expression. You were filtering out non-strings.

Conditional expression: *x* `if` *condition* `else` *y*. Return *x* if *condition* is True, otherwise return *y*.

```
names = [n.lower() if isinstance(n, basestring) else n for n in names]
```

Comment: haha thanks guys for the help. i do appreciate it.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to add a comment explaining what they find unsatisfactory in the answer?

Answer (score 1):

You may avoid use isinstance

```
[x.lower() if type(x)==str else x for x in names]
```

Comment: Why would you?  That prevents your code from working on types which derive from `str`.